# 64 Bit Assemblers issue

Tags: assembly

(Coding on win7 64 bit)

I have started to code in assembly yesterday, and I downloaded flat assembler.
Now, when I compile the code, I get a .fas file, and a .bin file.

So I heard you change their extensions to .exe or .com, and thats your built code.
But when I run it, I get an error because I'm trying to run a 32 bit application.

I tried:

1. Change the file execution to 32 bit through the file properties (Read it from google) but there is such an option there.
2. A differernt assembler - many. I've tried NASM 64 bit, same problem. And like 2 more which I have deleted since they didn't work.

Can anyone give me a download link to a WORKING 64 BIT ASSEMBLER? I've been looking for 1 all day :(

Plus if it has a dissassembling option it would be even better, but not necessery.

By the way, I rather an assembler which has an IDE too (like FASM, you code inside the program and it informs you of errors when you compile), NOT like NASM which is, simply, an assembler.

And I've got another question:
I have found many 32 bit assembler guides but much less 64 bit ones. Should I learn from the 32 bit too? I assume there are 64 bit only instructions, which I won't find in these guides, but as long as an all of the existing 32 bit instruction ARE EQUAL when coding in 64 bit, it's fine with me. So, are they?

And... If anyone got a good x64 guide, I'd appreaciate if he could post a link here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It creates a 32 bit excetuion files which I can not run on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FASM](http://flatassembler.net/download.php) *does* have x64 support. Did you read the [manual](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.1.19)? Did you look at the examples in *EXAMPLES\WIN64*?

Comment: Thanks, I have read it and used "format PE64" directive, but the moment I run the exe it crashes... ("...exe" has stopped working)

Comment: Still sounds like a problem in your program and not the assembler. Perhaps you should post the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hm I don't think so, since I thought it may be the cause, so I created a new .ASM file with the lines: format PE64 and then simply "mov al, 08" and this problem still comes.

Comment: [format PE64 / mov al,08 / ret] works just fine here. FASM 1.69.31, w7 x64 Professional.

Comment: I couldn't find your version in google, but 1.69.31 is mine too, just dont know if its x64. By the way, I added the instruction "ret" in the bottom of the code, and in a simple code it did work. but when using the "int" instruction it still "stop responding". Can you give me a link to your version? I'll try it.

Comment: There are not separate versions for x64 and x86. They are the same program. And how do you expect to use interrupts under win64? Are you trying to write 16-bit code? Linux code?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to *link* the generated binary. For NASM (Netwide Assembler) you can specify the output format, but [it defaults to `bin` if you don't supply the argument](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.09.09/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.2).

Simply specify the `nam -fwin64 ...` option. For more information on Windows-64 bit assembler in NASM, see [section 7.6 of the NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.09.09/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.6).

Comment: Just tried "nasm C:/first.ASM -fwin64 -o C:/first.EXE" and the output file still shows this 32 bit error. I'll read the manual now.